# Passing a function when all inputs are valid

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Interactive Credit Card display for a challenge on front end mentor.

I want to show the thank you div and remove the form once I press submit with every input being filled correctly. I am attempted to do so with an if statement.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cardValidation()
    addHtml()
    if(cardValidation(validSign(5))) //// Need Help Here.
    {
        passForm()
    }
}) 




function cardValidation() {

    const name = input_name.value.trim()
    const cardNumber = input_card_number.value.trim()
    const month = input_month.value.trim()
    const year = input_year.value.trim()
    const cvc = input_cvc.value.trim()



    let nameValid = /^[a-z\u00C0-\u02AB'´`]+\.?\s([a-z\u00C0-\u02AB'´`]+\.?\s?)+$/i
    let cardNumValidation = /^[0-9]{16}$/
    let cvcValid = /[0-9]{3}$/
    let monthValid = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))$/
    let yearValid = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9]|3[0-9]))$/

    const errorName = 'John Monroe Doe'
    const errorNumberCard = '0000000000000000'
    const errorMonth = '00'
    const errorYear = '00'
    const errorCVC = '000'

    if(name === '') {
        errorSign(input_name)
        nameHTML = errorName
        error++
    
    
    } else if (name.match(nameValid)){
        nameHTML = name
        validSign(input_name)


    }
    else {
        errorSign(input_name)
        nameHTML = errorName
        error++
    }
    
    if(cardNumber.match(cardNumValidation)){
       numberHtml = cardNumber
       validSign(input_card_number)

        
    }else {
        numberHtml = errorNumberCard
        errorSign(input_card_number)
        error++
    }

    if(month.match(monthValid)){
        monthHtml = month
        validSign(input_month)
    

    } else {
        errorSign(input_month)
        monthHtml = errorMonth
        error++
    }
    if(cvc.match(cvcValid)){
        cvcHtml = cvc
        validSign(input_cvc)

 

    }else {
        errorSign(input_cvc)
        cvcHtml = errorCVC
        error++
    }
    if(year.match(yearValid)){
        yearHtml = year
        validSign(input_year)


    }else {
        errorSign(input_year)
        yearHtml = errorYear
        error++
    }

    if(error > 0) {
        const errorNotification = document.querySelector("small")
        errorNotification.classList = 'error-notification'
    }

    
    

}

function addHtml() {
    const card_number = document.getElementById('js-card-number')
    const card_name = document.getElementById('js-card-name')
    const card_month = document.getElementById('js-card-expire-month')
    const card_year = document.getElementById('js-card-expire-year')
    const card_cvc = document.getElementById('js-card-cvc')

    card_name.innerHTML = `${nameHTML}`
    card_number.innerHTML = `${numberHtml}`
    card_month.innerHTML = `${monthHtml}`
    card_year.innerHTML = `${yearHtml}`
    card_cvc.innerHTML = `${cvcHtml}`

}

function errorSign(input){
    const formArea = input
    formArea.className = 'error'
}

function validSign(input){
    const formArea = input
    formArea.className = 'valid'
}

function passForm(){
    form.classList.add("finished-form")
    form.classList.add("thank-active")

}
```

I am aware as well that the error notification display for the small element is poorly designed, I'll fix that later.

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter to `cardValidation()` while the function declaration doesn't take any. And what is your issue?

Comment: My issue is that I'm trying to activate the `passForm()` once every input is running the validSign function but I don't know how to do that using if statements. Just hoping to get some insight and solutions to them. The parameter in the `cardValidation()` is an insight to me not knowing how.